# Child Page where the Parent Page is the same Permalink as a Post_Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I am in need of building child pages with the same URL as a post_type.

ie; my post_type is `work`

- I can publish a Page at `/work` and it works.
- My posts under `/work/thing-1` work
- A Page under `/work/page` does not work, as it’s looking for a `post_type` of page there.

How can I have the child pages work while the `post_type` exists with the same slug? If I change the slug to `works` everything works. But the client wants the `post_type` to have the same slug structure as the pages.

My `post_type` is:

```
        "name" => __( "Portfolios", "clients-child" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Portfolio", "clients-child" ),
    ];

    $args = [
        "label" => __( "Portfolios", "clients-child" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => [ "slug" => "work", "with_front" => false, "with_archive" => false ],
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => [ "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ],
    ];

    register_post_type( "portfolio", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_portfolio' );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14222317/3645650

Comment: That doesn't do the trick for me, unfortunately. Hoping for another solution.